# Drivers not supporting OS version?

Tags: windows-8, drivers

I currently run a 2 screen setup as I am a livestreamer over at Twitch. Both my screens are running off my one GTX 770 card.

However, I have recently been getting ridiculous numbers of BlueScreens, mostly `PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA` so I am having a complete driver check. In device manager some of my drivers are actually from 2006 for my Keyboard and Mouse. I have downloaded the latest drivers for them but it still says 2006 in device manager although that's a different story that I might ask as a different question at a later date.

My real question for today is what to do when the drivers for a product you need no longer get updated. As I said I have two monitors. One is an `AOC e2343F` and the other is an `Acer x223w`. The latter is a very old monitor and Device Manager says it's drivers are from 2009. When I go to the Acer website though, the download is only one from 2009 and for Windows Vista while I am running Windows 8. So what would be better, go driverless or keep these 2009 drivers?

**BSOD:**

```
Bugcheck string: PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA
Bugcheck code: 0x00000050
Param 1: fffff101`031b7b18
Param 2: 00000000`00000000
Param 3: fffff960`000b4180
Param 4: 00000000`00000002
Caused by Driver: ntoskrnl.exe
```

Comment: Please update your question to include all relevant details of your BSODs. Especially *all* numbers and, if present, filenames. Monitors don’t need drivers. These packages only contain color profiles.

Comment: @DanielB Thanks for your reply. As I said my question isn't about the BSOD's that was just background info. However, I will do so

Comment: upload the dmp files. Monitors don't need drivers so they don't cause the BSOD.

Comment: use WhoCrashed to analyse the BSODs